# Manipulating image output from shell in python without storing external file

Tags: python, shell, opencv, ffmpeg, imread

I am trying to store an image that is the result of ffmpeg.

Using this command, I have `frame.png` as an external file output:

```
ffmpeg -flags2 +export_mvs -i video.avi -vf 'select=gte(n\,200),codecview=mv=pf+bf+bb' -vframes 1 frame.png
```

I want to be able to load the frame.png directly into python, maybe using openCV but without saving it in the computer.

I thought of something like this:

```
cmd = "ffmpeg -flags2 +export_mvs -i video.avi -vf 'select=gte(n\,200),codecview=mv=pf+bf+bb' -vframes 1 frame.png"    

img = cv.imread(sp.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout = sp.PIPE, stderr = sp.PIPE).communicate()[0])
```

But I get an error:

> TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation

Any clue how to do this? The idea is, no frame.png should be generated as a file.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the ffmpeg bindings for python?

Comment: Not yet. Any you could suggest?

Comment: There are two projects that I can think of [ffmpeg-python](https://kkroening.github.io/ffmpeg-python/) and [PyAV](http://mikeboers.github.io/PyAV/).

Comment: Thank you. Will have a look at them.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the output file as `/dev/stdout` (you might need to specify the output format with `-f`)
Then you redirect your output to your python script like so

```
ffmpeg options /dev/stdout | python your_script.py
```

Then you can read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329445/how-to-read-image-from-in-memory-buffer-stringio-or-from-url-with-opencv-pytho) to see how you can read an image from a file object. Just replace `StringIO` with `sys.stdin`